# Adding observation to column does not work (Error: "subscript out of bounds")

Tags: r

I am trying to add one observation to a data frame with just one column.

```
fitted.values.elec <- rbind(fitted.values.elec[1:20,],5,725895,fitted.values.elec[-(1:20),])
```

Doing this I get:

1. The error "subscript out of bounds".
2. The data frame turns into a matrix. For class() I get matrix and array.

What do I miss here?

Thank you!

This is what I have:

```
  unique(fitted.values.elec[, 1])
1                         5.858684
2                         3.058384
3                         7.387295
4                         4.890524
5                         4.969836
6                         5.988356
7                         7.337252
8                         4.892035
9                         3.980916
10                        6.845760
11                        5.118041
12                        5.581330
13                        4.492655
14                        5.453386
15                        5.914754
16                        5.725895
17                        4.105544
18                        4.937531
19                        6.246537
20                        7.240994
21                        3.968855
22                        7.011589
23                        3.606612
24                        4.785006
```

This is what I want to get:

```
  unique(fitted.values.elec[, 1])
1                         5.858684
2                         3.058384
3                         7.387295
4                         4.890524
5                         4.969836
6                         5.988356
7                         7.337252
8                         4.892035
9                         3.980916
10                        6.845760
11                        5.118041
12                        5.581330
13                        4.492655
14                        5.453386
15                        5.914754
16                        5.725895
17                        4.105544
18                        4.937531
19                        6.246537
20                        5.725895
21                        7.240994
22                        3.968855
23                        7.011589
24                        3.606612
25                        4.785006
```

This is what I actually get:

```
> dput(fitted.values.elec)
structure(c(5.8586839266439, 5, 725895, 3.96885481552305, 3.05838393273725, 
5, 725895, 7.01158940397222, 7.38729508196495, 5, 725895, 3.60661157024705, 
4.89052437902574, 5, 725895, 4.78500551267813, 4.9698364008177, 
5, 725895, 3.96885481552305, 5.98835616438236, 5, 725895, 7.01158940397222, 
7.33725247524616, 5, 725895, 3.60661157024705, 4.89203539822832, 
5, 725895, 4.78500551267813, 3.9809160305324, 5, 725895, 3.96885481552305, 
6.84575955265579, 5, 725895, 7.01158940397222, 5.11804123711197, 
5, 725895, 3.60661157024705, 5.58132956152646, 5, 725895, 4.78500551267813, 
4.49265477439422, 5, 725895, 3.96885481552305, 5.45338645418218, 
5, 725895, 7.01158940397222, 5.91475409835944, 5, 725895, 3.60661157024705, 
5.72589531680329, 5, 725895, 4.78500551267813, 4.10554371001916, 
5, 725895, 3.96885481552305, 4.93753123438183, 5, 725895, 7.01158940397222, 
6.2465373961208, 5, 725895, 3.60661157024705, 7.24099378881861, 
5, 725895, 4.78500551267813), .Dim = c(4L, 20L))
```

Comment: @RonakShah fitted.values has 24 rows, I have added it to the question

Comment: But those are the values that you get after selecting 1st row `fitted.values.elec[, 1]`.

Comment: Yes, that is because for two observations, I get the same fitted value. Therefore, I want to add the value to this column that gets thrown out by unique manually

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
result <- c(fitted.values.elec[1, ][1:20], 5.725895, fitted.values.elec[1, ][-(1:20)])
```

From the first row it selects first 20 values, includes 5.725895 and then remaining values.